# Any idea how to get something like this to work?

Tags: plugins, php, html, links, array

This has been cleared. Leave it cleared.

Comment: Re: your request to "leave it cleared": The answer given makes no sense without the text of the question. Leaving the text of the question intact—even if it's a mistake you might find embarrassing—might also help another user who's having the same problem. This is a Q&A site, and without the Q, the value of the A drops significantly.

Answer (score 1):

The function `esc_html__`, it escapes html. the sumbol `<` is converted into its unicode, which is `&lt;`, and so on. You can see the wordpress documentation on what it does and how it works.

You need to change `esc_html__` to `__`.

When mixing html with wordpress localization functions its best to use sprintf. But for now just changing the function will do the trick

Comment: Could you add the updated code to your question?

Comment: Strange, should work. Don't know why the concatination but never mind that. Have you tried changing the string completely? something like `$result->error_message = 'test'`, to see if that changes the output, I say this because i want to make sure that the changes you made are in the right location